# Import XML objects in batches

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, optimization, import

I'm working on a PowerShell script that deals with a very large dataset. I have found that it runs very well until the memory available is consumed. Because of how large the dataset is, and what the script does, it has two arrays that become very large. The original array is something around a half gig, and the final object is easily six or seven gigs en-memory. My idea is that it should work better if I'm able to release rows as done and run the script in increments.

I am able to split the imported XML using a function I've found and tweaked, but I'm not able to change the data actually contained in the array.

This is the script I'm using to split the array into batches currently: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Split-an-array-into-parts-4357dcc1

And this is the code used to import and split the results.

```
# Import object which should have been prepared beforehand by the query 
# script. (QueryForCombos.ps1)
$SaveObj = "\\server\share$\me\Global\Scripts\Resultant Sets\LatestQuery.xml"
$result_table_import = Import-Clixml $SaveObj
if ($result_tables.count > 100000) {
  $result_tables = Split-Array -inArray $result_table_import -size 30000;
} else {
  $result_tables = Split-Array -inArray $result_table_import -parts 6
}
```

And then of course there is the processing script which actually uses the data and converts it as desired.

Comment: If you can split the XML into chunks that can be processed individually, you should also be able to process the XML data with a pipeline. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve (i.e. what structure does your XML data have, and what do you want to do with it in the end) instead of what you perceive as the solution. Also, the code snippet you posted can't possibly work as you expect. `$result_tables` is not yet defined when you try to check its `Count` property, and `>` isn't a comparison operator in PowerShell.

Comment: Should have put a .. in between the result table and the result_table_import. 

The processes imports a xml datafile which was exported from a previous script. The first script pulls the data from a SQL server, and the purpose of the script itself is processing the rows and splitting them based off of possible combos found from one of the columns. Unfortunately I have to be fairly ambiguous since it's a company-data security thing... (Even if there's no data actually revealed they're pretty stringent)

Answer (score 1):

For large XML files, I don't think you want to read it all into memory as is required with an XmlDocument or Import-Clxml.  You should look at the [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) as one way to process the XML file a bit at a time.